# Angular 5 app being cached only in IE and in prod

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache

I have this weird problem in IE (11) that my angular app caches the page. I have some images that show and hide based on a service call and only after I clear the temp files, the correct results show..

Chrome and Firefox work perfectly (also when doing ng serve locally, it works fine, the cache happens only when the app is deployed with -prod to iis)..

I have added  to the index.html but I still have the problem..

Any insights would be appreciated

thank you

Comment: add headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache') for http get request

Comment: but this happens for all static content on the page? and only in IE only?

Comment: IE-only. you can implement HttpInterceptor to add header.

Comment: @Yong, thanks, but i store an authtoken in the header, if i get a new httpheader for each intercept, then my authotken would get cleared?

Comment: No. If this token does not exist, you can also add this token in HttpInterceptor.

Answer (score 0):

@yong's answer was best. for the token, i added it to the httpInterceptor